# Break out of a conditional Statement

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

How can I get out of a conditional Statement? In the example below, is there any way to exit from the `if` statement and execute the `else` statement so that I need not write `logic1` twice?

Without using any methods?

```
status_invoked? = true
order_present? = true

if status_invoked?
  if order_present?
    # compute logic2
  else
    # compute logic1
  end
else
  # compute logic1
end
```

I think in C we have something called setJump() which jumps out of if statement and executes the else statement.

Comment: there's no loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably an easier way is something like this:

```
def compute_logic
  return unless status_invoked? #you could also throw an error here
  return compute(logic2) if order_present? 
  compute(logic1)
end

def compute(logic)
  ...
end
```

and define `order_present?` and `status_invoked?` either on initialization or in a private method, depending on your needs and how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
status_invoked? = true
order_present? = true
else_ecex=false

if status_invoked?
  # check if order_present?
  if order_present?
   #compute logic2
     #true else part 
     else_ecex = true
  end
end

#check even else is true or false
if(else_ecex == true)
#Your Code 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would instead go with a solution similar to dax. As that solution makes use of good helper methods. allowing you to manipulate those helper methods depending on your needs.

However, a possible solution using your code is to simply not have the elses, and use a return in order_present?.

```
status_invoked? = true
order_present? = true

if status_invoked?
  if order_present?
    # return logic2 here.
  end
end
# compute logic1
```

In this particular example, you only want to execute and return logic2 if status_invoked? and order_present? are both true, and you execute logic1 if you never reach the instructions inside of order_present?. However, even in this example, you would ideally create a helper methods, and pass logic1 and logic2 into it.

In my personal opinion, dax's method is the cleaner way to go. It reads clearer, as well as reads as a typical ruby formatting.